# Loading video files from device as `ByteData` flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filesystems

I'm using the flutter camera package to record videos and save videos to a temporary directory after which I use flutter's `ffmpeg` package to do some transformation. However, to achieved this, I first had to make a copy of the recorded video to create the output file path.

The challenge comes in when I'm trying to load the asset from the device. The block of code below does the copying and renaming of the file.

```
static Future<File> copyFileAssets(String assetName, String localName) async {
     ByteData assetByteData = await rootBundle.load(assetName);

    final List<int> byteList = assetByteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(assetByteData.offsetInBytes, assetByteData.lengthInBytes);

    final String fullTemporaryPath =
        join((await tempDirectory).path, localName);

    return new File(fullTemporaryPath)
        .writeAsBytes(byteList, mode: FileMode.writeOnly, flush: true);
  }
```

The issue lies with this line `ByteData assetByteData = await rootBundle.load(assetName);` 
I get this error message `Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.timz/files/timz/1585820950555.mp4`, but the weird thing is, this only happens when I run the build for the first.  Everything else works fine on subsequent hot restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later got this fix by myself `rootBundle` is meant for loading only assets you've declared their paths on your `pubspec.yaml` but somehow, it miraculously loads the saved file when hot restart was applied.

Reading the file as bytes gave what I wanted as load it with root bundle. Here's the code below.
     `Uint8List assetByteData = await File(assetName).readAsBytes();`